# Typescript @types/node import fs failed

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to read file in Typescripts. I am using @types/node instead of typings.

There is no compile error. But the fs in the debugger is shown as undefined.
What have I missed?

test.ts

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
fs.readFile('../some.xml', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./node_modules/@types//.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "test-helpers",
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./locale"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.20",
    "angular2-logger": "^0.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.29",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the compiled code. Is `require('fs')` there? Don't trust the debugger. It can lie. Any way, I think that `"module": "commonjs"` should be the proper setting for Node environment.

Comment: the compiled code does not have `require('fs')`. After I changed tsconfig.app.json to`"module": "commonjs"` the `fs` becomes an object with only __proto__.  `readFile()` is still undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is possible. Again, please, provide real information and not the one you see in debugger. If the error says 'readFile is not a function', the question is supposed to to reflect this. Please, provide a way to recreate this problem. A repo or something.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by installing the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) files for node:

```
typings install dt~node --global --save
```